# Form on PHP page with multiple submits changes CSS of page

Tags: php, html, css

I've created a PHP web form which when all the data is present has 2 submit buttons (Continue and Print). Continue calculates details based on the entered information and displays it on the page. Print performs the same calculations, but then creates a PDF in a new window.

When I click Print the original page still loads (which is fine) but the styling is altered.

To see what I mean head to [this page](http://www.freeyourwalls.com/product-selectors/controls/test.php) and for speed enter "1" in all text boxes except Position (which must be text). After you've clicked Continue, click Print to generate a PDF, then look back at the original web page to see altered styling.

Any ideas would be useful.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the tables overrunning the footer, get rid of the `height: 100%;` on `#prodselector_text`, solves the issue for me.

Comment: solves on me too.@adrian when you set some height/weight of a div to percentage-based value. The parent div must have explicit height/weight.